# how to set maximum size limit for incoming socket.io message

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

we want our server to block any messages that contain data larger than 7 kb.

our serverside code:

```
socket.on('startdata', function (data) {

        console.log(data.text);});
```

our clientside code:

```
        socket.emit('startdata', { text: 'testtext blah blah' });
```

is there a way to check  the data size and refuse to accept the message before the data gets passed to the `socket.on` function ?

Answer (score 2):

use buffer size

```
require('socket.io')(server, {
    maxHttpBufferSize: 1e9
});
```

Comment: Is it for incoming only or for outgoing as well ?

Comment: It's for both, general http size. I've tested it and works well

Answer (score 0):

I was also curious about this and did some digging.

It seems `destroy buffer size` is available for use which defaults to 100mb

important note:
`Used by the HTTP transports. The Socket.IO server buffers HTTP request bodies up to this limit. This limit is NOT applied to websocket or flashsockets.`
(https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO)

So sadly, it won't work with the websockets or flashsockets. Someone did try a pull request for this though: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/pull/888